# Prop undefined en hook mounted vuejs

Tags: vue.js, props

Tengo un componente padre, donde instancio un componente hijo de esta forma:

```
<template>
  <section class="container">
    <line-chart v-bind:cod-anillo="codigoAnillo"></line-chart>
    .
    .
    .
</template>

<script>
  import LineChart from '@/views/admin/Charts'

  export default {
     name: 'VueChartJS',
     components: {
       LineChart
     },
     data () {
       return{
         codigoAnillo: "",
       }
   },
   created () {
    this.codigoAnillo = this.$route.params.codAnillo;
   }
</script>
```

En el componente hijo intento leer la propiedad que paso, pero siempre optengo undefined:

```
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        props:{
          codAnillo:{
            type:String,
            default: ""
          }
      },
     }
   },
  };
 },
 beforeCreate() {
   console.log("codAnillo: "+this.codAnillo)
 }
};
</script>
```

He intentado verificar si llega en algun hoock como created o mounted y en todos llega el valor de ths.codAnillo como undefined.

Verificando en el inspector de objetos de vue, me doy cuenta que el parametro nunca llega al componente hijo, desconozco el porque:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Siguiendo su recomendacion cambie el formato a: <line-chart v-bind:cod-anillo="codigoAnillo"></line-chart> pero sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Y en el padre hay datos? porque en el create no se si estan creadas las variables.. no va en el mounted eso?

Comment: Y no necesitas un console.log si tenes instalado el plugin de vue para el navegador.... ahi ves las variables...

Comment: Da igual si lo pongo en el created, he probado en varias instancias del ciclo de vida y en ninguna toma el valor, en el padre le doy valor a la propiedad que paso en su instancia created y ahi si me lo marca, pero cuando quiero verlo en el componente hijo siempre es undefined

Comment: Añadi una captura del examinador de objetos de vue donde se aprecia que el valor nunca se pasa al componente hijo.